# How do you attach a viewable photo on SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-list

How do you attach a viewable photo on SharePoint List, instead of having to copy and paste the URL code of the attachment image?

Comment: You can add it as an attachment to a list item.

Comment: Do you want to display this image in the list view?

Comment: May be "Page Image" column from publishing site columns?